# Silverlight - User Control Binding

Tags: silverlight, user-controls

I am learning Silverlight. In the process, I'm trying to build a custom user control. My ultimate goal is to be able to write the following statement in XAML:

```
<my:CustomControl>
  <my:CustomControl.MainControl>
    <Canvas><TextBlock Text="Hello!" /></Canvas>
  </my:CustomControl.MainContent>
</my:CustomControl>
```

The content of the control will be wrapped in a custom border. Once again, this is just a learning exercise. To append my border, I have create the following UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
      <Border>
        <!-- CustomControl Content -->
      </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The code-behind for this file looks like the following:

```
public partial class CustomControl : UserControl
{
  public UIElement MainContent
  {
    get { return (UIElement)GetValue(MainContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MainContentProperty, value); }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty MainContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MainContent", typeof(UIElement), typeof(CustomControl),  
    new PropertyMetadata(null));


  public CustomControl()
  {
    InitializeComponent();            
  }
}
```

The thing I am having a problem with is getting the MainContent to appear in my CustomControl. I am confident that I am setting it properly, but I'm not sure how to display it. I really want it to be a DependencyProperty as well so I can take advantage of data binding and animations.

How do I get the MainContent to appear in the CustomControl?  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to wait until the rest of the control has been parsed so you need to hook the loaded event:-

```
public CustomControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(CustomControl_Loaded);
}
```

Then in the loaded event assign your MainControl property to the Child property of the border. To do that its best if you give your Border an `x:Name` which for now I'll simple call "border".

```
void CustomControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    border.Child = MainControl;
}
```

That'll get you going.  Of course you may need to deal with the MainControl property being changed dynamically so you need add a `bool isLoaded` field in your control and set that in the loaded event.  When true your `MainControl` setter should assign the incoming value to the `border.Child`.

Things can start to get more complicated and in fact I don't recommend this approach to creating a custom control.  For a better approach see [Creating a New Control by Creating a ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278064%28VS.95%29.aspx)